# Automatic doc build on ReadTheDocs.org on every new commit

Tags: read-the-docs, gitea

I want my docs on Read the Docs automatically build on every commit I do on a specific branch.

My [repo](https://codeberg.org/buhtz/buhtzology) is at Codeberg.org ([Gitea](https://gitea.io)). It doesn't use Sphinx but user specific [`build.command`](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/build-customization.html) executing `pydoctor`. This works fine when I click on *Build version*.

I can confirm that a commit doesn't trigger a build. As you can see in that screenshot the commit on `develop` didn't trigger a build of the doc. The last doc build was nearly two days before the last commit.

[image]

Comment: It looks like you figured it out: https://readthedocs.org/projects/buhtzology/builds/19017941/ What was the issue? Did not configure your repo to fire a webhook to RTD for that branch?

Answer (score 3):

OK, I got it. Now I document the process here. But be aware that I'm new to that topic and maybe there are more elegant ways.

The problem why I asked that question was that I didn't know about the basic concept of the webhook technology.

## The goal

Documentation on [Read the Docs](https://readthedocs.io) should be generated ("build") everytime a commit is made to a repository at [Codeberg.org](https://codeberg.org) which is code hoster running a [Gitea](https://gitea.io) instance.

## Concept

That Gitea instance need to be configured that way that it will send an event/trigger somewhere else. In this case to Read the Docs. On the other side Read the Docs need to be configured to receive that event and react on it with starting the build process.

The *webhook* on Codeberg.org is the *finger* and the *integration/incoming webhook* on Read the Docs is the *button*. You first have to configure Read the Docs (the *button*) and Codeberg (with it's *finger*) after it.

## Configure Read the Docs

This how to assume that the project is configured in Read the Docs and it building the documentation can be triggered manually without errors.

- Login into your Read the Docs account and select the project (1).
- Click on the button *Admin* (2).
- Click on *Integrations* in the left side menu (3).
- Click on the button *Add Integration* (4).
- Select *GitHub incoming webhook* without wondering about that GitHub is not Gitea.

[image]

- A page comes up with the configured *webhook* offering an URL like `readthedocs.org/api/v2/webhook/buhtzology/222213/`.

## Configure Codeberg.org

- Go to the *Settings* of your repository. (1)
- Select *Webhooks* (2).
- Select *Add Webhook* (3).
- Select *Gitea* (4).

[image]

A form comes up with several fields

- *Target URL*: Paste in the URL you have from the Read the Docs webhook in the previous section. But don't forget to add `https://` in front of it.
- *HTTP Method*: Should be "POST" by default.
- *POST Content Type*: "application/json" (also "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" works)
- *Secret*: Leave it empty.

Also choose a *Trigger* of your choice and make sure that the *Activate* checkbox at the end of the form is selected.

Click the button *Add Webook*.

Select the webhook again from the *Webhooks* list and find the button *Test Delivery* at the end. Click on it!

## Check Read the Docs

When everything is fine this activaty indicator should come up on the previously configured webhook at Read the Docs.

[image]